# How to set image height & width 100% in reactXP

Tags: reactxp

I have a background image and i want to set the height and width to 100%. 
What is the best way to proceed in ReactXP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<View style={{ width: 200, height: 300, backgroundColor: "red" }}>
  <Image
    source="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
    style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
    resizeMode="cover"
  />
</View>
```

Only tested on the Web. If it's not working on React Native, you'd have to measure the wrapping View with `onLayout` to get its width and height.